# PHP getRows how can i add an outer join?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following and it works in returning the assigned cases for the logged in user:

```
public function getRows($table, $conditions = array()){
    $sql = "SELECT ";
    $sql .= array_key_exists("select", $conditions)?$conditions['select']:'*';
    $sql .= ' FROM '.$table;
    $sql .= " WHERE assigned_to = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"; 
    if(array_key_exists("where", $conditions)){
        $sql .= " WHERE assigned_to = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
        $i = 0;
        foreach($conditions['where'] as $key => $value){
            $pre = ($i > 0)?' AND ':'';
            $sql .= $pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

I just received the requirement to join another table to this query to display only a log file for a particular case when the edit button is clicked on, but not sure where to add an OUTER JOIN.

For instance, I wish to add the lead_status_changes table where lead_status_changes.id = whp.id (with whp being the main table).

Comment: Join clauses go after the initial table mentioned in the FROM. I'm sure you can find many examples in tutorials etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Assuming you have established a database connection using PDO

function getOuterJoinData($table1, $table2, $joinCondition, $columns)
{
    $query = "SELECT " . implode(", ", $columns) . " FROM " . $table1;
    $query .= " LEFT JOIN " . $table2 . " ON " . $joinCondition;

    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $result;
}

// Example usage
$table1 = "users";
$table2 = "orders";
$joinCondition = "users.id = orders.user_id";
$columns = array("users.name", "orders.order_number", "orders.amount");

$data = getOuterJoinData($table1, $table2, $joinCondition, $columns);

// Do something with the retrieved data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['name'] . " - " . $row['order_number'] . " - " . $row['amount'] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

In the above example, the getOuterJoinData function accepts the table names ($table1 and $table2), the join condition ($joinCondition), and an array of column names ($columns) that you want to retrieve from the join. It constructs the SQL query using the outer join (LEFT JOIN in this case) and executes it using PDO.

Adjust the table names, join condition, and column names according to your specific scenario. Also, make sure to establish a database connection using PDO before using this function.

Note: It's crucial to validate and sanitize user input to prevent SQL injection attacks. The above example does not include input validation, so make sure to implement proper validation and sanitization techniques before using the user-provided input in the SQL query.

Comment: I tried to shorten my code, but it does have validation.  My only question here is how to display the data from a second table, which is read-only.